# How can I convert many XLSX files into many CSV files using NESTED FOR LOOPS in R?

Tags: r, loops, csv, nested, xlsx

I've been trying to convert many .xlsx into many .csv

First, I made a list with all .xlsx that I want to be converted.

```
> especies
 [1] "Aburria jacutinga.xlsx"       "Acrobatornis fonsecai.xlsx"   "Alectrurus tricolor.xlsx"    
 [4] "Amadonatur lacernulatus.xlsx" "Amazona pretrei.xlsx"         "Amazona rhodocorytha.xlsx"   
 [7] "Amazona vinacea.xlsx"         "Anodorhynchus leari.xlsx"     "Anthus nattereri.xlsx"       
[10] "Antilophia bokermanni.xlsx"
```

Then, I edit the elemmnts in order not to have any space in the name and create another vector. It ended like this:

```
> nomes_
 [1] "Aburria_jacutinga"       "Acrobatornis_fonsecai"   "Alectrurus_tricolor"     "Amadonatur_lacernulatus"
 [5] "Amazona_pretrei"         "Amazona_rhodocorytha"    "Amazona_vinacea"         "Anodorhynchus_leari"    
 [9] "Anthus_nattereri"        "Antilophia_bokermanni"
```

Then I tried the following nested for loops to convert each .xlsx file into .csv files:

```
for (file in especies){
  xlsx_objeto<- readWorksheetFromFile(file=file, sheet=1, keep=c(2,3,4,6,7,8,9,10,13,18))
  for( j in nomes_){
    write.csv(xlsx_objeto,file=paste0("./csv/",j,".csv"))
  }
}
```

What I've got is one .csv file for each element in `nomes_`. That's ok. 
But inside these .csv file are exactly the same. They all have the data from the last .xlsx file in the `especies` list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I could manage that. Here it goes the code. Sorry the comments are in portuguese.

```
library('XLConnect')
library('foreach')
# Cria uma lista com todos os arquivos em xlsx
especies<-list.files(pattern = "\\.xlsx$")
# Eliminar algum arquivo indesajado que esteja na pasta
especies<-especies[-c(1:41)]
## Cria um vetor que contenha os nomes desejados para serem os nomes dos arquivos finais.
# Retira a extensão ".xlsx"
nomes<-gsub(pattern=".xlsx",replacement="",especies)
# Substitui todo espaço por "_"
nomes_<-gsub(pattern=" ",replacement="_",nomes)
# Retira todo "." Atenção se quiser substituir pontos ".", estes devem estar entre colchetes assim: "[.]"
nomes_<-gsub(pattern="[.]",replacement="",nomes_) 
# Cria um csv com a lista dos nomes dos arquivos.(Opcional)
write.csv(nomes_,file="./csv/_lista_especies.csv", quote=FALSE)
## Usando FOREACH LOOP para converter cada arquivo xlsx em um csv que terão como nome o elementos da lista criada acima.
# Detalhes do uso do foreach em http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/vignettes/foreach.pdf
foreach(file = especies, j = nomes_) %do% {
  xlsx_objeto<- readWorksheetFromFile(file=file, sheet=1, keep=c(2,3,4,6,7,8,9,10,13,18))
  write.csv(xlsx_objeto,file=paste0("./csv/",j,".csv"))
}
```